# Is XClaim / claim supported in redis spring data - ReactiveRedisOperations.opsForStream()

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, lettuce, spring-data-redis-reactive

To build a reliable message queue using redis streams, i am using spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive and lettuce dependency to process the messages from redis stream. Though i am able to add, read, ack and delete message through the api available in `ReactiveRedisOperations.opsForStream()` in the form of consumer group, i couldn't find an api to claim a pending message which are not acknowledged for 5mins though its available under `this.reactiveRedisConnectionFactory
                                .getReactiveConnection()
                                .streamCommands()
                                .xClaim()`. But i don't want to have a boilerplate code to manage the exceptions, serialization, etc. Is there a way to claim a message using `ReactiveRedisOperations.opsForStream()`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ReactiveStreamOperations.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without spring data redis, using lettuce client library directly i am able to get the pending message as well claim a message as below

```
public Flux<PendingMessage> getPendingMessages(PollMessage pollMessage, String queueName) {
    Predicate<PendingMessage> poisonMessage = pendingMessage -> (pendingMessage.getTotalDeliveryCount()<=maxRetries);
    Predicate<PendingMessage> nackMessage = pendingMessage -> (pendingMessage.getElapsedTimeSinceLastDelivery().compareTo(Duration.ofMillis(ackTimeout)) > 0 );

    return statefulRedisClusterConnection.reactive()
        .xpending(queueName, pollMessage.getConsumerGroupName(), Range.unbounded(), Limit.from(1000))
        .collectList()
        .map((it) -> ((PendingMessages)PENDING_MESSAGES_CONVERTER
                .apply(it, pollMessage.getConsumerGroupName()))
                .withinRange(org.springframework.data.domain.Range.unbounded()))
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
            .filter(nackMessage)
            .filter(poisonMessage)
            .limitRequest(pollMessage.getBatchSize());
}
```

In order to claim the message, again i have used the api available in lettuce library

```
public Flux<StreamMessage<String, String>> claimMessage(PendingMessage pendingMessage, String queueName, String groupName, String serviceName) {
    return statefulRedisClusterConnection.reactive()
            .xclaim(queueName, Consumer.from(groupName, serviceName), 0, pendingMessage.getIdAsString());
}
```

At the moment, getting pending message from redis through spring-data has issues hence i have used lettuce library directly to get a pending message and claim it.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-1160